# Ruby - Naming Convention - letter case for acronyms in class/module names?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I need to create a class that represent "SVN" inside a module called "SCM". But I don't know what is the convention when dealing with acronyms in Ruby, and could not find anything relevant in Google, except "Camel case is preferred".

Should I call it `SCM::SVN` or `Scm::Svn`? Is there a convention for this?

Comment: The Ruby convention is to give it a name like [trollop](https://rubygems.org/gems/trollop), [asset_hat](https://github.com/mintdigital/asset_hat) or even Tenpuku (Japanese for Subversion according to Google Translate). ;-)

Comment: @MarkThomas Fun fact: _tenpuku_ (転覆) can mean "subversion," but the more common usage is for things like [capsizing and rollovers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E8%BB%A2%E8%A6%86&tbm=isch&biw=1438&bih=719&sei=bKs7T-3qDcydmQX1rri8Cw). And now you know. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SCM::SVN` looks best to me. Rails is full of classes like ERB, ORM and [OMFGIMATEAPOT](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/models/teapot.rb#L18-22). And that's not to mention things like JSONSerializer. Ruby's source has [a bunch of acronyms](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6533f070ba616662b7ab7504f7bc2a0827394a89/lib/resolv.rb#L1717-2156), too. The most obvious example to me is `YAML`. The standard as I've seen it is to upcase letters for CamelCase but generally not to downcase them (although Rails has opinions on model names).

If you have grep and the source code you can see plenty of examples with something like

```
grep -r 'class [A-Z]\{3,\}' <path/to/source>
# or, if you only want acronyms and nothing like YAMLColumn:
grep -rw 'class [A-Z]\{3,\}' <path/to/source>
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me to browse the Ruby source code and look for acronyms. Very clever! I'll use `SCM:SVN`. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Add the following to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'SVN'
end
```

Now running `$ rails g model SVN…` will create a class named `SVN` in a file named `svn.rb` and an associated table `svns`.

Comment: Well, my question was about ruby in general, not rails in particular, but your answer could help someone else. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  This makes all the difference.  Try `'svn'.classify` before and after adding it to the inflector.  In other languages/platforms, there's no such thing, so it makes sense to use something that can be converted in an automated way.  But activesupport lets me write whatever looks better.  The end result is I love Ruby even more.

Answer (score 4):

I think that `SCM::SVN` looks better (aesthetically), and I've seen libraries that use the same convention. It's really just a matter of what you think reads better.

(However, note that if you are building a Rails project, and want this module to be autoloaded from the /lib directory, you may have to use `Scm::Svn`.)

Comment: Does the above suggestion of using the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` fix the autoload issue?

Comment: @MegaTux 12 years after writing this answer, I'm not using Rails at this time so I can't readily check. If you check and confirm that it does fix the issue, feel free to edit that into my answer.