# Rails custom validator name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a custom Rails validator that I named `URLValidator` to validate URLs. This seems to be in line with [Rail's naming conventions for acronyms in camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293031/ruby-naming-convention-letter-case-for-acronyms-in-class-module-names).

In my model, I'm validating my URL as follows:

```
validates :url, :presence => true, :url => true
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
`rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'UrlValidator' (ArgumentError)
```

Is there any way I can get Rails to use the correct convention or to specify the name of the custom validator I want to use for :url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your validator should be named `UrlValidator` (the result of camelized `'url'`):

```
# Validator for the `url` attribute
class UrlValidator< ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # to be implemented
  end
end

def Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
   validates :url, :presence => true
end
```

[Link to doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html)

or, to stick with the name `URLValidator`, you can use [`validates_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_with) :

```
class URLValidator< ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate(record)
    # check on record.url, to be implemented
  end
end

def Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
   validates_with URLValidator
end
```

or a more generic version (if the name of the attribute is not always `url`)

```
class URLValidator< ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate(record)
    value = record.send(options[:on])
    # check value, to be implemented
  end
end

def Foo < ActiveRecord::Base 
   validates_with URLValidator, :on => :url
end
```

Comment: This seems to go against Ruby naming conventions. Isn't there some way I can do this without renaming my validator?

Comment: Maybe with `validates :url, :presence => true, :URL => true` you could use `URLValidator`

Comment: @LandonSchropp I've edited my answer, maybe this solution better suits you.